# How to remove substring up to a certain character?

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

We have a string that is constantly generating the following pattern below. Ideally we would like to get rid of the string (all characters) up to the first "/" found. I have tried the following but it is not working. Need assistance to see what i am missing.

The goal is to remove all characters before the first "/" and the "/" itself from the beginning. The tricky part is that the string before the first "/" can vary in length.

Example strings:

1. test-item/test-test1/test-2/test
2. test-item2/test
3. abdc/test/test/test

Example code that i tried (where $str is example strings above):

```
$patt = '/.+\/';
$repl = '';
$str = preg_replace($patt, $repl, $str);
```

Current output:

1. test
2. test
3. test

Desired string output:

1. test-test1/test-2/test
2. test
3. test/test/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method using the substr() and strpos() functions that will work:

```
 $str = substr($str, strpos($str, '/') + 1 );
```

Comment: thank you for the help. That resolved the issue as i was able to remove the string and character i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$exp = explode("/", "test-item/test-test1/test-2/test");
$result = implode(array_shift($exp), "/");
```

for each path you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$str = preg_replace('^.*?\/(.*)\/.*$', '$1', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on all examples you gave - good luck

```
<?php
$string = 'test-item/test-test1/test-2/test';
$character   = '/';
$position = strpos($string, $character);


    $string2 = substr($string, $position+1);    
    echo "New string is '$string2'";
?>
```

Comment: If any of these answers worked perhaps you could accept one or rate the answers thankyou

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @DragonSpirit :
$str = substr($str, strpos($str, '/') + 1 ); should work !

Comment: the OP did not ask or tagged as javascript or whatever language this is, probably java.